# How to use preg_split to get the desire result

Tags: php

I have a string like this

```
1 BDP-105159857   2602        BARUN SINHA                     MTE02 MTE07 MTE08 PHE11 PHE14
```

I want to split it like

1, BDP, 105159857,   2602,        BARUN SINHA,                     MTE02, MTE07, MTE08, PHE11, PHE14

If I use

```
preg_split('/[-, ]+/',$string);
```

Then it splits the name (BARUN SINHA) in two parts as expected. But I want to keep it together. How to overcome it?

This is a screenshot of my data

[image]

Comment: Are those long blanks multiple spaces or tabs? And is the string always formatted like the example?

Comment: I dont know whether these are multiple spaces or tabs.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective data.

Comment: @AsimDas is that MYSQL table or any data file ?

Comment: I am asking because if you tell me that then i can provide you best solution for your problem.